# derivative B-spline with own knot set

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, spline

Define the spline function of degree $q$ on the interval $[\xi_0,\xi_K]$ $$f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{K+q}b_j B_j(t)$$ 
 where $B_j$ are degree $q$ B-spline basis functions determined by the knots $\xi_{-q}<\xi_{-q+1}<\ldots<\xi_{0}<\xi_{1}<\ldots<\xi_{K}$. I know there is an expression for the derivative when we have multiple end knots, but what is the expression for this kind of knot sets? See http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-derv.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Derivative_expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the formula for the derivative of a b-spline curve does not make any special assumptions about the form of the knot sequence. So, the formulae given in Shene's notes should work fine, regardless of what knots you use in the original curve.

First, a basic fact: if you want to define a set of b-spline basis functions of a given order, then the number of knots you need will be equal to the number of basis functions plus the order. If you form a curve from these basis functions, then the number of coefficients (control points) will equal the number of basis functions, of course. So, another way of stating this basic rule is
$$
\text{number of knots} = \text{number of control points} + \text{order}
$$
Here's another way to say more-or-less the same thing. Suppose you have a sequence of knots $\{\xi_i\}$, and you want to define $K+q$ b-spline basis functions of degree $q$ (order $q+1$) using these knots. Further, suppose that you want the basis functions to be defined on the interval $[\xi_0, \xi_K]$. Then you will need to have $q+1$ knots that are $\le \xi_0$ and $q+1$ knots that are $\ge \xi_K$. Often this is achieved by giving $\xi_0$ and $\xi_K$ multiplicity $q+1$, but this isn't the only way.

So, the description in your question is flawed. Your curve has $K+q$ coefficients (control points), and order $q+1$ (degree $q$), so the number of knots must be $(K+q)+(q+1) = K+2q+1$. I think your knot sequence ought to be $\xi_{-q}, \ldots, \xi_{K+q}$, not $\xi_{-q}, \ldots, \xi_{K}$. This will give you a total of $K+2q+1$ knots, as required. The b-spline curve is defined on the interval $[\xi_0, \xi_K]$.

From Shene's notes, you can see that the derivative will be a b-spline curve that is again defined on the interval $[\xi_0,\xi_K]$. It will have $K+q-1$ coefficients, and order $q$ (degree $q-1$), so the number of required knots is $(K+q-1) + q = K+2q-1$ knots. This is two less than the number of knots used by the original curve.

To get the knot sequence for the derivative curve, you simply drop the first and last knots, so you end up with the sequence $\xi_{-q+1}, \ldots,\xi_{K+q-1}$.

Again, we don't need any special assumptions about the multiplicities of end knots.

There is another description of b-spline curve derivatives [here](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node17.html). It doesn't tell you any more than Shene's notes, but the array indexing is a bit more sane, so it might be easier to understand.

Comment: Why is my description flawed? I defined a b-spline basis for the vector space of spline functions of degree q on $[\xi_0,\xi_K]$ with knot set $\xi_0<\xi_1<\ldots <\xi_K$.

So you actually are saying that I should define the additional knots outside the domain of interest in a different way. Even then I do not see how deleting two knots will give you only one less basis function compared to the "primitive" function.

Comment: For example, the dimension of that vector space is $K+q$, how do you reconcile that with having $K+2q+1$ different knots...

Comment: The rule is: number of knots = number of control points + order. You have $K+q$ control points and order $q+1$, so you need $K+2q+1$ knots.

Comment: When you pass from the original function to its derivative, the number of control points is reduced by one, and the order is reduced by one, so the number of required knots is reduced by two.

Comment: If you want to define b-spline basis functions on an interval $[\xi_0, \xi_K]$, then, yes, you will need addtional knots outside this interval. In fact, if the basis functions are of degree $q$, you will need $q$ more knots that are $\le \xi_0$ and $q$ more knots that are $\ge \xi_K$. Often this is achieved by giving $\xi_0$ and $\xi_K$ multiplicity $q+1$, but this isn't the only way.

Comment: Regarding "how do you reconcile ...". This is *always* true. The dimension of the vector space is the number of coefficients (control points). In your case this is $K+q$. Then the number of knots is this plus order (where $\text{order} = \text{degree}+1$). So, again, the number of knots is $(K+q)+(q+1) = K+2q+1$. You seem to be expecting that the number of knots should be equal to the dimension of the spline space. This is definitely not true.

Comment: I overlooked the fact that B-splines starting at the right end of the domain need other knots $\geq \xi_K$.